# Copy/duplicate file from source to destination folder using File

Tags: android

I am writing a sync operation between 2 folders.

Effectively, i want the contents of a folder in the internal storage to be the same as the contents of a folder from the external sd card.

flow:
1) the target folder would delete all its .bmp files. 
2) the .bmp files from the source folder will be copied to the target folder

I've looked at the File class [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html) from google. Unable to find a method that allows you to copy a file.

any idea where can i find a class/method that enables me to do so?

Comment: If you google for how to copy a file you find a thousand answers.

Comment: And further you could react to the helpfull comments given to you in your other post. Dont come here to only consume please.

Comment: @greenapps my bad, i thought you are not supposed to comment stuff like "thanks" "it works" etc. Seeing that there was nothing wrong with my previous code, i just voted up your comment. i have googled file operations, read the google `File` documentation and cant seem to find a simpler method like`file.delete()`. so im wondering if i missed out anything.

Comment: `not supposed to comment stuff like "thanks" "it works" etc. `. Indeed. I saw that often advertised too. But i consider that as a very bad advise. Of course everybody who helps wants to hear if suggestions work. In normal life you would say thank you too. And we hate 'thanks in advance'. You dont even have to say thank if you only would just react.